# Laravel select not all related model

Tags: laravel, relation, laravel-query-builder

How to filter relationships?

I found models from related data.
How do I select only those related models that match the search term?

Basic query

```
 $toDolists = ToDoList::select(['*']);
```

```
  foreach ($tags as $tag) {
                $toDolists->whereHas(
                        'item.tag',
                        function ($query) use ($tag) {
                            $query->where('tags.name', $tag);
                        }
                );
            }
```

I want to select related models (item) that match the search conditions.

Comment: use `pluck` in the `tags` collection and then `whereNotIn` for your second query :)

Answer (score 1):

That will generate a very horrible query (`AND WHERE EXISTS( ... )` for each tag).

You can use `whereIn` instead.

```php
ToDoList::whereHas('item.tag', function ($query) use ($tags) {
        $query->whereIn('name', $tags);
    })
    ->get();
```

Comment: No, i want select not all realted models.  Not all items

Comment: so `Tag::whereIn('name', $tags)->get()` ?